# Android green accent color

Tags: android

I would like to use this accent (green?) color in my app

[image: https://cdn.phonemore.com/content/2015/jpg/2833.jpg]

I have found that it's probably https://www.google.pl/search?ei=FbhVW4tulIebBcC_tMAL&q=%2380CBC4&oq=%2380CBC4&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l2.0.0.0.18385.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.vOOE7QAH0nk

but is that color defined somewhere and I can use it or I need to define it in my resources?

Comment: accent color is defined in your colors.xml file under values folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below style into your values/styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#80cbc4</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define this `color` definition in `colors.xml` (e.g. as the value of `@color/colorPrimary`) rather than using it directly in `styles.xml`? Especially if it's going to be used in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not pre-defined in your app.
You have to define the colour explicitly in `res/colors.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

go to the res =>values=>colors
replace your color with colorAccent

Answer (score 0):

That's the Android OS accent color. You can get it using:

`android.R.attr.colorActivatedHighlight`

Use this function to resolve attributes (Kotlin extension)

```
fun Context.themeColor(@AttrRes attrRes: Int): Int {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute (attrRes, typedValue, true)
    return typedValue.data
}
```

So your code would look like this:
`themeColor(android.R.attr.colorActivatedHighlight)`